# How to read numbers from a file and make each of them a element of a list in python, rather than a big element consist of all of them?

Tags: python

I tried to read some integers from a txt, and makes them into a list in python using the code like below:

```
nums=list()
txt=open('integers.txt')
for i in txt:
    nums.append(i)
print(nums)
```

But I got the output like:

```
['5 34 33 45 6 4 23 76 434']
```

It looks ok, but actually there's only one element of this list, which is 
`'5 34 33 45 6 4 23 76 434'`, not a series of them like `['5', '34', '33', '45', '6', '4', '23', '76', '434']`, I don't know how to solve the problem...
Thanks for your help

Comment: It sounds like you need to be using [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on each line in the file.

Comment: Kindly Edit your Question...

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that your loop `for i in txt` is actually iterating over the *lines* in the file.  So it looks like you have a 1-line file and you are just appending the [last] line into your list.

Instead, you probably want to split up the elements (split by whitespace):

```
with open('integers.txt') as f:
    nums = f.read().split()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums=list()
txt=open('integers.txt', 'r')
print [int(number) for number in txt.read().split()]
txt.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `join()` method.

```
nums=list()
txt=open('integers.txt')
for i in txt:
    nums.append(i)
print(' '.join(nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split each line to get each individual entry:

```
nums=[]
txt=open('integers.txt')
for i in txt:
    nums.append([item for item in i.split()])
print(nums)
```

Comment: This will result in `[['5', '34', '33', '45', '6', '4', '23', '76', '434']]`